# Calculated property isn't filled by Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I've made a calculated property with `@Formula` annotation on one of my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Searchable(name = "First name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable=false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Searchable(name = "Last name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable=false)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Formula("FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME")
    private String loFstLstName;

    public String getLoFstLstName() {
        return this.loFstLstName;
    }

    public void setLoFstLstName(String loFstLstName) {
        this.loFstLstName = loFstLstName;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have only nulls in `persons` list in the following code:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT loFstLstName FROM Person");
List persons = q.getResultList();
```

`PERSON` table contains records having values different from null in `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` fields. I'm using Hibernate 3.3 with PostgreSQL 8.4.9. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that every value of `loFstLastName` returned by your query is null? If so, how are you running the query? Via JPA's EntityManager? Via a Hibernate Session? Show your code. Also, while it wouldn't explain *all* the values being null, note that `'something'||NULL` is `NULL`; you must use `coalesce(FIRST_NAME,'') || ' ' || coalesce(LAST_NAME, '')` if `FIRST_NAME` and/or `LAST_NAME` may be null.

Comment: The query is being runned via JPA's EntityManager. Every value in its result is null. I've tried to use `coalesce` as you advised. It doesn't help.

Comment: Unless @axtavt's answer (which is a good point) resolves the issue, please update the question to show the actual code you're running for the problem query.

Answer (score 2):

You should not mix different access types (i.e. placement of annotations on properties and on fields) inside the same entity (unless you explicitly configure it with `@Access`). Try the following:

```
@Formula("FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME") 
public String getLoFstLstName() {
    return this.loFstLstName;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It causes the following exception on deploy: `java.lang.ClassCastException:org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column`